# How to add item with one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to add a new article to my DB but have some problems with one to many relationship field Category. I want to implement SelectList to choose one category and add its Id to the CategoryId column in my Articles table.

```
public class Article
{        
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeroImage { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }  //implementing one to many relationship with category
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}


 public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Articles = new List<Article>();
    }
}

public class ArticlesView
{
    public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CreateNewArticle()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewArticle(ArticlesView av)
    {
        byte[] imageData = null;


        Article artical = new Article { Name = av.Name, CategoryId = av.CategoryId,
            ShortDescription =av.ShortDescription, Description=av.Description, Date = av.Date };

        db.Add(artical); // adding artical
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

And here's my View:

```
    @model MyBlog.Models.ArticlesView
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateNewArticle";
}

<h2>CreateNewArticle</h2>

<form asp-action="CreateNewArticle" asp-controller="home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label">Category</label>
        <select asp-for="Categories" asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories"></select>
    </div>   


    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Don't pay attention on other fields. 
But this doesn't work for for me. It's smth wrong with adding id and idk what. Pls help.

Comment: How does it not work? Please elaborate.

Comment: @GertArnold, exception: SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Articles_Categories_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "...", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are not trying to select multiple values from `selectList`.

So what you should do is simple, you should target the `CategoryId`.

```
div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label">Category</label>
        <select asp-for="Categories" asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories"></select>
</div>
```

These `asp-for` values should be `CategoryId`, but you gave `Category` and `Categories` instead.

Comment: You are right! It's simple but starts to work properly. Thank you.